# Use Serial in Arduino as variable

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I would like to choose which Serial should be used on my Mega (e.g. Serial for development & testing, and then Serial3 for communication with another board). I came with this code:

```
HardwareSerial HWSerial = Serial; //or Serial1, Serial2, Serial3
void setup() {  
  HWSerial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  HWSerial.println("Hello world!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

However, this produces only first two bytes and a NUL (`"He␀"`).

**What am I doing wrong?**

*Note:* I know I could use

```
HardwareSerial* HWSerial = &Serial; //or Serial1, Serial2, Serial3

void setup() {  
  HWSerial->begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  HWSerial->println("Hello world!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

which works. I was, however, in fact planning to use ArduinoJSON and the `serializeJson(JSONObj, serial)` function which won't accept a pointer, so I'm stuck there - and my approach compiles, but again, produces only first two bytes...

Comment: `HardwareSerial& HWSerial = Serial;`

Comment: Thank you, @Juraj. Problem solved. And I have to read again about references and pointers, since c++ definitely is not my mother tongue.